# What does "then" compile to, so that it works in older browsers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Happy new year!

I'm watching a react udemy tutorial (the one from Maximillian Schwarzmüller), and the guy told me that I can use the asynchronous ES6 function .then() without a problem, because it will also work in older browsers "since the code gets compiled to code which also works in older browsers"

And now I'm asking myself, what does .then() get compiled to, so that it will also work in older browsers?

Does he mean that it gets compiled to some C++ render stuff through the render engine which understands it, or does he mean that it gets compiled to easier normal javascript like ES6 arrow functions get compiled to through Babel?

Could it also be that I understand the word "compile" wrong? I am a little bit confused.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Generally these are called "transpilers" which are source-to-source compilers. Instead of going from, say, JS to assembly, they compile JS to different JS.

Comment: .then gets transpiled to some sort of closure/callback.

Comment: you may look at https://www.promisejs.org/implementing/. It's also good practice to implement simple Promise yourself if you lack in understanding of the concept :)

Comment: *"the asynchronous ES6 function .then()"*: this is worded in a strange way. `then` is not an asynchronous function. Asynchronous functions are declared with the `async` keyword. What you *can* say is that the function that is passed as first argument to `then` will be executed asynchronously (provided the promise fulfils).

Comment: If only support for `then` is needed (and not `async` / `await`) then compatibility can be provided through a polyfill. For real syntax changes (like arrow functions, `async`, `await`) a transpiler is needed.

Answer (score 3):

> What does `.then()` get compiled to, so that it will also work in older browsers?

Nothing different at all. Code using ES6 promises is still syntactically valid ES5 code (assuming it uses no other ES6 features), unlike new syntax (e.g. arrow function, class definitions etc) it does not need to be transpiled.

`then` is just a plain method call (in both ES5 and ES6), however the definition of the method is provided by the ES6 environment. In ES5, where promises began to be used, you needed to include a promise library (like Q or Bluebird). To make code that assumes the ES6 `Promise` to exist run in older browsers, you need a **polyfill** (e.g. from [one of](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#promise) [these](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/316/top-5-best-javascript-promises-polyfills) lists). The polyfill is just a small ES5 script that implements the same API.

Answer (score 1):

*Compiling* (depending on a definition) is basically transforming code in one language to code in another - this process is sometimes also referred to as *translation*. You can compile C++ to native code, but you can just as well compile code in Java to C++ or compile code in one version of the language to another. And that's basically what JavaScript compilers do - they translate code written in newer version of the standard (e.g. ES6) to an older version (e.g. ES5). The kind of compiler that compiles code in one version of the language to another is often referred to as *transpiler*.

As for what the compiler will translate the code to: it depends on a compiler, but very often some kind of a polyfill (basically a custom implementation of a built-in feature) will be injected at the beginning of the result file, making the missing feature available across your codebase.